# double join between json array lists with n1ql couchbase

Tags: json, join, couchbase, sql++, nosql

I have following json entry that is called User. There is a **selectedItemList** list that keeps items under responsible for a user.

```
"myproject": {
  "_class": "com.demo.model.entity.User",
  "active": true,
  "createDate": 1470826033000,
  "description": "",
  "firstname": "Tom",
  "selectedItemList": [
    "MTR44",
    "MTR55",
    "MTR66"
  ],
  "type": "user",
  "username": "tom"
}
```

There are following 3 items that keep itemId as unique value

```
    "myproject": {
  "_class": "com.demo.model.entity.Item",
  "deleted": false,
  "factor": 0,
  "itemId": "MTR66",
  "type": "item"
}

"myproject": {
  "_class": "com.demo.model.entity.Item",
  "deleted": false,
  "factor": 0,
  "itemId": "MTR55",
  "type": "item"
}

"myproject": {
  "_class": "com.demo.model.entity.Item",
  "deleted": false,
  "factor": 0,
  "itemId": "MTR44",
  "type": "item"
}
```

there is following orders that keeps item id's as a list

```
"myproject": {
    "_class": "com.demo.model.entity.Orders",
    "model": "DR-503",
    "deleted": false,
    "itemIdList": [
        "MTR66",
        "MTR55"
    ],
    "type": "order"
}

"myproject": {
    "_class": "com.demo.model.entity.Orders",
    "model": "DR-504",
    "deleted": false,
    "itemIdList": [
        "MTR44"
    ],
    "type": "order"
}
```

my question is: i try to get order list of items under responsible user "tom".
my way is: get item from orders with join. but i couldn't join that with user tom's selectedItemList with itemId(because it is not an objest, it is a json array).

```
SELECT META(myproject).id as _ID, META(myproject).cas as _CAS, myproject.*  
FROM myproject
LEFT JOIN myproject item ON KEYS ARRAY itemId FOR itemId IN myproject.itemIdList 
LEFT JOIN ........
```

so, i couldn't write after second join, i don't have any idea about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
create index idxorderlist on myproject(itemIdList);

SELECT *
FROM  myproject u USE KEYS ["tom"]
      LEFT OUTER JOIN myproject item ON KEYS u.selectedItemList
      LEFT OUTER JOIN myproject `order` ON KEY `order`.itemIdList FOR item
;
```